# how to run an executable in a sibling directory while retaining all its config files?

Tags: windows, powershell

Folder/File structure:

```
main\exe1Folder\exe1.exe --config asdf1.txt 
main\exe2Folder\exe2.exe --config asdf2.txt
```

Current folder: main

How can I run these two executables in folder main using Powershell script while having the executables realizing its own configuration files in their own folders?

Comment: It's difficult to predict unknown exe files behaviour. Did you try to supply a relative/absolute path for the config file?

Comment: the config files and the executable are all in their own folders. I can run them separately, but i want to be able to create a powershell script that runs multiple exes.